# Retorno do Ajax passar para o PHP

Tags: php

Não sei se é possível, pois sei que javascript é cliente e PHP é servidor. 
Mas eu gostaria de pegar o retorno que vem do ajax (após executar o PHP e retornar) e armazenar em uma variável do PHP.
Exemplo abaixo;

```
<script>
    $.ajax({

        url: 'assets/php/advantage-club.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            "pass": "3d1fa6s0df51as8das6d2f1as036f15as8df90"
        }

    }).done(function(r) {
        AQUI EU TENHO O RETORNO,
        QUERIA COLOCAR O RETORNO
        NUMA VARIAVEL DO PHP PARA TRABALHAR ABAIXO
    });
</script>

<?php
    echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($r);
    echo '</pre>';  
?>
```

Seria possível isto?

Comment: Oloco, meu ! Pq essa necessidade em fazer essa exibição no PHP ?

Comment: curiosidade, o que eu preciso posso fazer via for() e exibir abaixo. Mas fiquei curioso em entender como eu não consigo jogar o valor para o PHP novamente. @GatodeSchrödinger

Comment: Respondi abaixo... mas caso você precise no PHP chamar outra página php para trabalhar com o resultado dessa segunda página, aí ao invés de usar o ajax, você usa o cURL. Verifique se no seu servidor ou no wampp, xampp da vida se a extensão cURL está ativa.

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é possível.

O `PHP` é executado no servidor e tem como retorno um `HMTL`.

O `ajax` no entanto é executado no navegador através de javascript. Logo o seu navegador não tem como atribuir dinamicamente um valor a uma variável `PHP`.

Como você deve saber, a chamada `ajax` envia uma requisição HTTP para a sua página 
`assets/php/advantage-club.php` e no seu caso está retornando um conteúdo `HTML`.

O que você pode fazer é, ao invés de retornar um `HTML`, trocar o `dataType` para `JSON` e na sua página `PHP` retornar um objeto `JSON` que pode ser originado de um `array` utilizando a função `json_encode` :

Exemplo em `assets/php/advantage-club.php`:

```
<?php

   $dados = array( 'nome' => 'Willian', 'telefone' => '99 99999-9999' );
   exit(json_encode($dados) );

?>
```

Na sua função `javascript`:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({

        url: 'assets/php/advantage-club.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            "pass": "3d1fa6s0df51as8das6d2f1as036f15as8df90"
        },
        success: function(obj){
            console.log(obj.nome); // Saída será: Willian
            console.log(obj.telefone); // saída será : 99 99999-9999
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log(err.status); //saída será 500, 404, 403... códigos de erro http
        }

    });
</script>
```